# Pandas DataFrames in Python: How do I flatten data and not lose rows where some data is missing? (json_normalize, where function)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm just starting to learn Pandas and DataFrames in Python, and while my use case is to take EC2 EBS Volume data and flatten it into a CSV, where some volumes have attachment data and some don't, what I'd like to do is to use Pandas fully to do this (instead of iterating over the data beforehand to add dummy data that's missing).

So here's the simplest use case that I can think of:

```
import pandas as pd

states = [{'state': 'Florida',
           'shortname': 'FL',
           'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
                        {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
                        {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
          {'state': 'Ohio',
           'shortname': 'OH',
           'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
                        {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]},
          {'state': 'New York',
           'shortname': 'NY',
           'counties': []}]

counties_normalized_data = pd.json_normalize(data=states, record_path='counties', record_prefix='county.', meta=['state', 'shortname'])

print(counties_normalized_data)
```

This results in:

```
  county.name  county.population    state shortname
0        Dade              12345  Florida        FL
1     Broward              40000  Florida        FL
2  Palm Beach              60000  Florida        FL
3      Summit               1234     Ohio        OH
4    Cuyahoga               1337     Ohio        OH
```

While this makes sense, I'd like to not lose New York entirely.  Instead, I'd like to keep New York and have county.name and county.population set to "N'A".

So I started playing around with the `where` function in `DataFrame`, but as you probably already know, it won't work unless all states get the exact same number of counties.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd

states = [{'state': 'Florida',
           'shortname': 'FL',
           'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
                        {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
                        {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
          {'state': 'Ohio',
           'shortname': 'OH',
           'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
                        {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]},
          {'state': 'New York',
           'shortname': 'NY',
           'counties': []}]

df = pd.DataFrame(states)


df['counties'] = df['counties'].where(df['counties'].str.len() > 0, [{'name': 'Westchester', 'population': 3456}, {'name': 'Putnam', 'population': 1000}])
```

Which results in the following exception:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,) (2,)
```

So what I'm trying to determine is what is an appropriate way to normalize data wherein sometimes there are subsets of that data that won't have values.

I've read about normalizing just subsets of the data and then merging afterwards, but I just haven't come across yet a concrete example that I can readily understand.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.